# Java "pulse" between threads

Tags: java, thread-safety, concurrency, simulation

I have two threads. One runs a simulation and one runs a UI.

In the UI, it is possible to trigger a "tick" of the simulation. There are a few constraints:

- Ticks run on the simulation thread
- Each tick takes a bit of time to complete.
- When the user asks for `n` ticks, `n` ticks should be completed, even if they are requested during the execution of a tick.

To manage the triggering of ticks between threads, I have created a `Pulse` class. Here it is:

```
public final class Pulse {

    private final Object Lock = new Object();

    private volatile int count;

    public Pulse() {

        super();

        count = 0;
    }

    public void pulse() {

        synchronized (Lock) {

            count++;

            Lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void waitForPulse() throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (Lock) {

            while (count == 0) {

                Lock.wait();
            }

            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

A single `Pulse` instance is shared between the UI and simulation threads.

In the UI thread I would have something like:

```
void onTickRequested() {

    simulationPulse.pulse();
}
```

And in the simulation thread I have something like:

```
while (isRunningSimulation) {

    myPulse.waitForPulse();

    tick();
}
```

Will my code work as expected? Is it thread-safe?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What do you mean by, "Will my code work as expected?" Have you not tested your code?

Comment: Well it works in my simple tests, but I don't know if I have applied the concurrency primitives correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good code! Just a few points:

1. `super();`

   This line of code is automatically put in by the compiler and is unnecessary to write it yourself. If it is a habit that you have a hard time breaking, you may leave it, as it does not compromise speed, but I would leave it out, as it does clutter code slightly.
2. Over-spacing

   Though spacing is good, too much space makes code hard to read as well. Your spacing is good, with one thing: you have a space between each line. Maybe it helps you, but I find it difficult to read.

   Compare:

   > ```
   > public final class Pulse {
   >
   >     private final Object Lock = new Object();
   >
   >     private volatile int count;
   >
   >     public Pulse() {
   >
   >         super();
   >
   >         count = 0;
   >     }
   >
   >     public void pulse() {
   >
   >         synchronized (Lock) {
   >
   >             count++;
   >
   >             Lock.notifyAll();
   >         }
   >     }
   >
   >     public void waitForPulse() throws InterruptedException {
   >
   >         synchronized (Lock) {
   >
   >             while (count == 0) {
   >
   >                 Lock.wait();
   >             }
   >
   >             count--;
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   and:

   ```
   public final class Pulse {

       private final Object Lock = new Object();
       private volatile int count;

       public Pulse() {
           super();
           count = 0;
       }

       public void pulse() {
           synchronized (Lock) {
               count++;
               Lock.notifyAll();
           }
       }

       public void waitForPulse() throws InterruptedException {
           synchronized (Lock) {
               while (count == 0) {
                   Lock.wait();
               }
               count--;
           }
       }

   }
   ```

   Note that I've kept some spaces.
3. `private final Object Lock = new Object();`

   Java conventions state that variable names are camelCase, not PascalCase. Change `Lock` to `lock`.